# How to duplicate Oracle database without sysdba privilege

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have an oracle 11g installed on a linux machine. I want to duplicate the database on my local 64-bit windows machine. We have total 403 tables and a few of them have foreign key constraints. I am not a dba so I don't have the sysdba privilege. Also I cannot shutdown the remote database. Is there a quick way to do this rather than I copy the tables one by one? Thanks

Comment: [exp\imp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm) - executed entiarly on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you do not have DBA role granted and not having access to server machine, you won't be able to do a cold backup and install in on your machine, because cold backup requires database getting shut downed.

Secondly, you can't use rman utility either.

You can use expdp utility to get database exported as files and import it to your db with impdp utility.But in order to get data exported you at least need **CONNECT** and **RESOURCE** roles granted to your user ( Assuming you already have CONNECT otherwise you won't be able to connect to db at all ) and with those roles you can only import objects you already have access to. Including objects you own.

On the other hand, if you need a full database export, then you need **EXP_FULL_DATABASE** granted.  DBA, SYS and some other roles has this role included. So your best chance is to contact dba's asking for the role granted to your user, see how they react to that.